# Using Apple MDM Configurator to block all videos from playing on iOS device

Tags: ios, console, applescript

There is demand from a significant group of people who would like to block all videos from playing on their iPhones. Is it possible to do this using Apple's MDM Configurator to create an apple profile on the device that has video playback blocked?

I do not see the option [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/restrictions) in apple's documentation for device management

Maybe there is way to make custom restrictions without having to jailbreak the phone?

Comment: Which videos?  Videos in Safari?  What about videos in the YouTube app, the Netflix App, a million other apps that play video?

Comment: @Paulw11 lets assume downloading new apps will be restricted, so videos from all builtin players such as safari, camera, gallery, iMessage, etc

Comment: Then no,  that isn't an available policy.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks. Is this possible and relatively easy if jailbroken?